# Webpack doesn't pick up local node_modules updates

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server, yarn-link, yalc

I have a package `A` that depends on package `B`. I am using `yalc` to update `B` and publish changes locally so that `A` can pick up these changes.

I can see that the changes are copied into `A`'s `node_modules` folder, however webpack doesn't seem to pick them up. When running `A` in a dev server, I still see the old code. Restarting the dev server doesn't help. Even `yarn install --check-files` doesn't help. The only thing that helps is nuking the whole `node_modules` and reinstalling.

Project `A` was creates with `create-react-app`

`package.json` has the following:

```
dependencies: {
...
@company_name/project_name: "file:.yalc@company_name/project_name"
... }
```

I am using `yarn 1.22`

Answer (score 6):

**tl;dr**

`yalc push --sig`

**Explanation**

Webpack [caches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72343913/39979), aggressively, modules based on the `package.json` version

Changing the version number, rebuilding and running `yalc push`, which does trigger an immediate rebuild in `webpack-dev-server`.

`yalc push` and `yalc publish` support a `--sig` option, which adds the current build signature to the deployed packages' `version` numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In case of an angular project, you can delete the following folder:
`.angular/cache` This will cause webpack to rebuild the node_modules folder. The `.angular/cache` folder is a hidden folder in the root of your project.